# Why I get "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied" error when I using youtube-dl in c# process class?

Tags: c#, process, exe, access-denied, youtube-dl

when I run youtube-dl.exe with c# process class on server, it returns below error in StandardOutput:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpc7h_sle1\build\youtube_dl\__init__.py", line 449, in main
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpc7h_sle1\build\youtube_dl\__init__.py", line 416, in _real_main
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpc7h_sle1\build\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 367, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpc7h_sle1\build\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2100, in _setup_opener
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpc7h_sle1\build\youtube_dl\utils.py", line 642, in make_HTTPS_handler
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 439, in create_default_context
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 390, in load_default_certs
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 377, in _load_windows_store_certs
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

What is these errors?**I don't have these paths and files with these directories.**
And Here is my code

```
   string ydlPath = Server.MapPath("/ydlPath/youtube-dl.exe");
    string tempLocation = Server.MapPath("/ydlPath/");

    System.IO.StreamReader errorreader;
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ydlPath ;
    //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-F \"" + Url + "\"";
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = tempLocation;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a] \"" + Url + "\"";
    proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.Start();
    errorreader = proc.StandardError;
    string Output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
```

I used this on my local and it works fine.
Also when I use youtube-dl.exe **with cmd on server or on my local** I don't have problem.

> How can I solve this problem?  Anyone can help me?

Comment: Because access to the path you're trying to access is denied

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen What should I do now?

Comment: Set the permissions properly?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes I think. root folder have iis and administrator permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem solved and this issue related to python bug.Details exist on :https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/10766

Comment: @YenChiHsuan,I have a question.with this compressed python version,I can't download from somelinks,but with exe version it's work.what is the reason of this?

Comment: A possible reason is that the two files are based on different youtube-dl versions.

Comment: @YenChiHsuan How can I handle it?can I?

Comment: Hi parsa, I guess you've opened https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/10766? Could you move to Github for further discussions? Commenting on Stackoverflow is not as convenient.

Comment: @YenChiHsuan Ok